# Bootstrap Tabs Links Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My tabs are not working,every thing is fine .Links are not working properly,,  please help.i try every method but no use.I try CDN , then local  file also

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">

    <ul class="nav nav-stacked nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a href="#C" data-toggle="tabs">C#</a></li>
        <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tabs">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="" data-toggle="tabs">jQuery</a></li>
        <li><a href="" data-toggle="tabs">PHP</a></li>
    </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="C">
                <p>C# IS DEVELOPED BY MICROSOFT CORP IN 2000</p>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="home">
                <p>This is HOME</p>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't include the bootstrap js file, only the css.

Comment: @razethestray i connect every single file, but still nothing happening

Comment: You need to run some JS to activate them according to the docs... http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include jquery file to run the bootstrap i.e
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js . You do not need to add any other jquery code.
And also data-toggle will be **tab** not "tabs".

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tab">
        <li class="active"><a href="#C" data-toggle="tab">C#</a></li>
        <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">jQuery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">PHP</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You are life saviour

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the bootstrap js file then also give your menu an id and add a click handler to handle the tab switching, like this:

```js
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> 
  <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-stacked nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a href="#C" data-toggle="tabs">C#</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tabs">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-toggle="tabs">jQuery</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-toggle="tabs">PHP</a></li>
  </ul> 
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="C">
      <p>C# IS DEVELOPED BY MICROSOFT CORP IN 2000</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="home">
      <p>This is HOME</p>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```